# Node module unzip file with password

Tags: node.js, npm, unzip

Im looking for node package to unzip password protected zip files. 
As of now i have looked [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzipper)

But the above provides functions to open the files and parses the files one by one. I require to just extract the files at one place.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, and if you still are looking for an answer
In the same package check out these functions:

[Unzipper File Wise Extracting Options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzipper#openfilepath-options)

[Method specific extract](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzipper#openmethodextract)

These can help you extract the files (all or selected ones) at the desired location

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unzip a password-protected file from a directory -

```
const unzipper = require("unzipper");

const unzipAndUnlockZipFile = async (filepath, password) => {
  try {
    const zipDirectory = await unzipper.Open.file(filepath); // unzip a file
    const file = zipDirectory.files[0]; // find the file you want

    // if you want to find a specific file by path
    // const file = zipDirectory.files.find((f) => f.path === "filename");

    const extracted = await file.buffer(password); // unlock the file with the password (password is optional, do not pass this if the file is not password-protected)

    console.log(extracted.toString()); // file content
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

const zipFilePath = "./src/application.zip";
const password = "1234";
unzipAndUnlockZipFile(zipFilePath, password);
```

If you want to unzip and extract the file from a buffer then the solution would look like below -

```
const unzipper = require("unzipper");

const unzipAndUnlockZipFileFromBuffer = async (zippedFileBase64, password) => {
  try {
    const zipBuffer = Buffer.from(zippedFileBase64, "base64"); // Change base64 to buffer
    const zipDirectory = await unzipper.Open.buffer(zipBuffer); // unzip a buffered file
    const file = zipDirectory.files[0]; // find the file you want

    // if you want to find a specific file by path
    // const file = zipDirectory.files.find((f) => f.path === "filename");

    const extracted = await file.buffer(password); // unlock the file with the password (password is optional, do not pass this if the file is not password-protected)

    console.log(extracted.toString()); // file content
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

const zippedFileBase64 = "{{BASE64}}";
const password = "1234";
unzipAndUnlockZipFileFromBuffer(zippedFileBase64, password);
```